# What OS things need to be checked for deploying shared library

Tags: gcc

I am facing a problem, by code was compiled in gcc version 3.4.6 (RED had Linux) and share library is deployed on some other linux system it has gcc version 4.1.2 . The code is crashing while exiting. I know compiler has nothing to do once the shared library is created. Am i wrong?

If not what other OS features are dependent on execution of shared library as on some of the linux envoirnment my code is crashing while exiting.

Answer (score 0):

The code may depend on a specific version of libc, so you should probably check that.